# Grunt not compiling less anymore

Tags: css, gruntjs, less

I've been working on the project and have been doing my layout for the past hour.
Everything was working fine until just a moment ago.

I put a wrong code in my style.less (the file im working in) and it gave the error on the watch. Once I removed the error and saved the less folder that is being watched, it compiled again (like usual).

What happened though: The site reverted back to it's original bootstrap (even though grunt is giving the message that the file has been changed).

Example:

```
Running "less:development" (less) task
>> 1 stylesheet created.

Running "watch" task
Completed in 1.419s at Fri May 20 2016 18:42:19 GMT+0000 (UTC) - Waiting...
```

Here is my workspace:

[image: workspace]

And my grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          yuicompress: true,
          optimization: 2
        },
        files: {
          "client/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css": "client/lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      styles: {
        files: ['client/less/style.less'],
        tasks: ['less'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch']);
};
```

The file i'm working in is: style.less, and the css file is located in:

```
"client/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

Anyone have an idea how this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code.
Might want to restart your workspace or computer?

I've had some glitches where my workspace bugged out and didn't record any operations done in the terminal.

Comment: Wow.. thanks.. I deleted the bootstrap.css. Restarted my computer & workspace and when I restarted 'grunt' it went back to the editted state.